# Show a context menu when the a column in a QTableView is selected

Tags: c++, qt, selection, qtableview

I have a QTableView and I am trying to show up a context menu which appears only when a whole column is selected. I also need the number of the column selected for further purposes. I connected the `currentChanged()` signal of the Selection Model (reimplemented as `TabSelModel` here) to this slot

```
void TabSelModel::CheckSelection(const QModelIndex& mod)
{
    qDebug() << "Inside mod.column=" << mod.column();
    QModelIndexList ls = selectedIndexes();

    foreach(QModelIndex i, ls)
        qDebug() << i.column() << "," << i.row();

    if(isColumnSelected(mod.column(),mod))      //never evaluates to true
        ColSelected = qMakePair(true,mod);
}
```

And the first time I select the first column of the table the output is just

```
Inside mod.column= 0
```

When I select the next column I get

```
Inside mod.column= 1
0 , 0
0 , 1
0 , 2
0 , 3
...
0, 66
```

Which means that `mod.column()` gives 1 but `selectedIndexes()[0].column()` gives 0 which is why (I think) I never manage to get into the `if` clause. Why is that? And how to fix that?

Analysing the beheaviour it seems that `selectedIndexes()` registers the indexes that were *previously* selected while the index I receive with `currentChanged()` is the current one. If this is true I still do not know how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at this link.
https://forum.qt.io/topic/31233/how-to-create-a-custom-context-menu-for-qtableview

Assuming that you highlight a column by clicking on its header:

```
table->horizontalHeader()->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
connect(table->horizontalHeader(),
        SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)),
        SLOT(customHeaderMenuRequested(QPoint)));
```

.

```
void Widget::customHeaderMenuRequested(QPoint pos){
int column=table->horizontalHeader()->logicalIndexAt(pos);

QMenu *menu=new QMenu(this);
menu->addAction(new QAction("Header Action 1", this));
menu->addAction(new QAction("Header Action 2", this));
menu->addAction(new QAction("Header Action 3", this));
menu->popup(table->horizontalHeader()->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));
}
```

To get the column selected:

```
ui->tableView->currentIndex().column();
```